# receive input to find number of multiples

Tags: java

I'm having some trouble getting the correct output format for my homework. Here it is:

> Write a program that accepts an integer n and an integer m from user and that prints a
>   complete line of output reporting the first m multiples of n. For example, if user input is:
>   m = 5, n = 3;
>
> It should produce this output:
>   The first 5 multiples of 3 are 3, 6, 9, 12, and 15.

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Assignment2Part3 {
public static void main (String[] args) {

  //declaring the two variables being entered
  int n = 0;
  int m = 0;

  //declaring answer variable
  int a = 0;

  //declaring scanner input
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("Please enter the number you want to find multiples of");
  n = input.nextInt();

  while(true) {

     System.out.println("Please enter the amount of multiples you want to see");
     m = input.nextInt();

     if (m <= 0) {

        System.out.println("Please enter an integer greater than zero");
     }
     if (m > 0) {

        break;
     }
  }
 System.out.println("The first "+n+ " multiples of "+m+" are: ");
  for (int i=1; i<=m; i++) {

     a =i*n;
     System.out.println(a);
  } 
}
}
```

This is what the output looks like right now:

```
Please enter the number you want to find multiples of
3
Please enter the amount of multiples you want to see
5
The first 3 multiples of 5 are: 
3
6
9
12
15
```

How do I get the output to look like "The first 5 multiples of 3 are 3, 6, 9, 12, and 15." ?

NOTE: This assignment is for an introductory course and we have just covered for loops.

Comment: Try to use `System.out.print(...)` instaed of `System.out.println(...)`. Print first the `m-1` multiples and then the last one.

Comment: thanks so much I got the format to look like I need it to now!

Comment: There's a little error in your code: In the last text output you are telling to print the first `n` multiples of `m`. However, it is the other way round - you can easily check this in the output you provided.

Comment: Nice catch I didn't notice that at all, haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Printing them out on one line.
   By changing `System.out.println` to `System.out.print` you can make multiple prints display on the same line.
   You also need to `print` a separator (`", "`) before every number (except the first), so that the numbers don't just pile up on top of each other.
2. Before the last number, you want to print `"and"`.
   You can do by altering the behaviour when the loop is at the final step (which is when `i==m`).

This gives something like this:

```
System.out.println("The first "+m+ " multiples of "+n+" are: ");

for (int i = 1; i <= m; ++i) {
    if (i > 1) {
        System.out.print(", ");
        if (i==m) {
            System.out.print("and ");
        }
    }
    System.out.print(i*n);
}
System.out.println(".");
```